# ¿Cómo puedo ver las métricas de una GAN (Generative Adversarial Network)

Tags: python, tensorflow, redes-neuronales, keras, inteligencia-artificial

Estoy programando una **GAN simple para crear números a partir de un ruido aleatorio**.

He logrado programar la red neuronal y funciona todo bien, pero no he encontrado **como puedo hacer para ver la accuracy** o la **loss** para poder verlas pintadas en un gráfico, con redes neuronales convolucionales por ejemplo, es más fácil, ya que en el `.compile()` le defino las métricas que quiero usar, pero **en este caso no se cómo puedo hacerlo**.

Este es el código de mi red neuronal:

```
import os
import time
import imageio
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras, GradientTape
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Reshape, Conv2D, Flatten, Conv2DTranspose, BatchNormalization, LeakyReLU
from tensorflow.keras.losses import BinaryCrossentropy
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

print('GPU available:', tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))
print('tensorflow version:', tf.__version__)

 

(train_images, _), (_, _) = mnist.load_data()

train_images.shape

train_images = train_images.reshape(train_images.shape[0], 28, 28, 1).astype('float32')
 
train_images = (train_images - 127.5) / 127.5 

BUFFER_SIZE = 60000
BATCH_SIZE = 256
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_images).shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE).batch(BATCH_SIZE)

 
def create_generator_model():
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Dense(7 * 7 * 256, use_bias = False, input_shape = (100,)))

  model.add(Reshape((7, 7, 256)))

  model.add(Conv2DTranspose(128, (5, 5), strides = (2, 2), padding = 'same'))
  model.add(BatchNormalization())
  model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.01))

  model.add(Conv2DTranspose(64, (5, 5), strides = (1, 1), padding = 'same'))
  model.add(BatchNormalization())
  model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.01))

  model.add(Conv2DTranspose(1, (5, 5), strides = (2, 2), padding = 'same', activation = 'tanh'))

  return model

generator = create_generator_model()

generator.summary()

noise_dim = 100
noise = tf.random.normal([1, noise_dim])
 
image_generated = generator(noise, training = False)

plt.imshow(image_generated[0, :, :, 0], cmap = 'gray')

 
def create_discriminator_model():
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Conv2D(32, (5, 5), strides = (2, 2), padding = 'same', input_shape = [28, 28, 1]))
  model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.01))

  model.add(Conv2D(64, (5, 5), strides = (2, 2), padding = 'same'))
  model.add(BatchNormalization())
  model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.01))

  model.add(Conv2D(128, (5, 5), strides = (2, 2), padding = 'same'))
  model.add(BatchNormalization())
  model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.01))

  model.add(Flatten())
  model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

  return model

discriminator = create_discriminator_model()

discriminator.summary()

 
decision = discriminator(image_generated)
print(decision)

 

generator_optimizer = Adam(learning_rate = 1e-4)
discriminator_optimizer = Adam(learning_rate = 1e-4)

@tf.function
def train_step(images):
  noise = tf.random.normal([BATCH_SIZE, noise_dim])

  with GradientTape() as gen_tape, GradientTape() as disc_tape:
    images_generated = generator(noise, training = True)

    real_output = discriminator(images, training = True)
    fake_output = discriminator(images_generated, training = True)

    gen_loss = generator_loss(fake_output)
    disc_loss = discriminator_loss(real_output, fake_output)

  gen_gradients = gen_tape.gradient(gen_loss, generator.trainable_variables)
  disc_gradients = disc_tape.gradient(disc_loss, discriminator.trainable_variables)

  generator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gen_gradients, generator.trainable_variables))
  discriminator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(disc_gradients, discriminator.trainable_variables))

def generate_images(model, test_input):
  predictions = model(test_input, training = False)

  fig = plt.figure(figsize=(grid_size_x,grid_size_y))

  for i in range(predictions.shape[0]):
      plt.subplot(grid_size_x, grid_size_y, i + 1)
      plt.imshow(predictions[i, :, :, 0] * 127.5 + 127.5, cmap='gray')
      plt.axis('off')     
             
  plt.show()

grid_size_x = 10
grid_size_y = 10
seed = tf.random.normal([grid_size_x * grid_size_y, noise_dim])

def train(dataset, epochs):
  for epoch in range(epochs):
    start = time.time()

    for image_batch in dataset:
      train_step(image_batch)

    generate_images(generator, seed)
   
    print('EPOCH {} completed in {} segundos'.format(epoch + 1, time.time() - start))

  generate_images(generator, seed)

EPOCHS = 100
history = train(train_dataset, EPOCHS)
```

¿Alguien sabe como puedo incorporar las métricas en este modelo para ver la precisión y la loss?

Estoy usando tensorflow 2.4 y python3

Answer (score 0):

Pues prácticamente lo tienes todo hecho, lo que te queda es **imprimir el resultado de tu función de perdidas** para el generador y el discriminador.

En la función `train_step()` que has creado para calcular la perdida del gradiente y su dirección, utilizas las dos funciones de perdidas que te has creado previamente `generator_loss()` y `discriminator_loss()`.

Lo que tienes que hacer es retornar esta perdida que ya tienes calculada, es decir tu función quedaría así:

```
@tf.function
def train_step(images):
  noise = tf.random.normal([BATCH_SIZE, noise_dim])

  with GradientTape() as gen_tape, GradientTape() as disc_tape:
    images_generated = generator(noise, training = True)

    real_output = discriminator(images, training = True)
    fake_output = discriminator(images_generated, training = True)

    gen_loss = generator_loss(fake_output)
    disc_loss = discriminator_loss(real_output, fake_output)

  gen_gradients = gen_tape.gradient(gen_loss, generator.trainable_variables)
  disc_gradients = disc_tape.gradient(disc_loss, discriminator.trainable_variables)

  generator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gen_gradients, generator.trainable_variables))
  discriminator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(disc_gradients, discriminator.trainable_variables))
  
  #Esto es lo único que cambia de la función
  return gen_loss, disc_loss
```

Después como esta función la aplicas en la función que te creas `train()` hay ya puedes imprimirlo, almacenarlo en listas, lo que tu quieras, en este ejemplo lo imprimo:

```
gen_loss_step = []
disc_loss_step = []
def train(dataset, epochs):
  for epoch in range(epochs):
    start = time.time()

    for idx, image_batch in enumerate(dataset):
      gen_loss, disc_loss = train_step(image_batch)
      
      #Almacenamos para despues poder hacer un gráfico o lo que queramos
      gen_loss_step.append(gen_loss)
      disc_loss_step.append(disc_loss_step)
     
     #Printeamos para imitar el comportamiento de Tensorflow y sus funciones
      if idx %50 == 0:
        tf.print(f"perdida generador step {idx}: ", loss_gen)
        tf.print(f"perdida discriminador step {idx}: ", loss_disc)
     

    generate_images(generator, seed)
   
    print('EPOCH {} completed in {} segundos'.format(epoch + 1, time.time() - start))

  generate_images(generator, seed)
```

### Explicación

Te he dejado comentarios en el código, pero los cambios que he hecho en esta función son:

1. Creo dos listas donde ir almacenando los resultados de ambas funciónes de perdidas `gen_loss_step` y `disc_loss_step` y durante el proceso de entrenamientos vamos guardando hay los resultados con el método `.append()`. Esto te servira para verlas, guardar el proceso cuando acabe, hacer un gráfico, lo que tú quieras.
2. utilizo `enumerate()` para hacer el módulo `%` del número y así evitar imprimir cada paso de actualización de pesos de tus redes neuronales. Le he puesto para imprimir cada 50 pasos por epoca, tu puedes cambiarlo a lo que desees.
3. utilizo `tf.print()` para printear exclusivamente la perdida, ya que si utilizas `print()` se verá el tensor entero.

Comment: Muchas gracias, y para ver la accuracy?? como lo podría representar? Muchas gracias

Comment: Pues exactamente igual, el método a hacer es el mismo! No utilizas ninguna métrica de accuracy  en tu código, pero si la implementaras al igual que has hecho con la función de perdidas. Para mostrarla simplemente sería repetir lo mismo que hemos hecho con la función de perdidas.